# Getting the humanTiming function to work with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

This is arnorhs' code, which converts a date & time into "human" timing, such as "3 days ago":

```
$time = strtotime('2010-04-28 17:25:43');

echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago';

function humanTiming ($time)
{
    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment

    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second');

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

It works great when typing the date manually.

But when I use a string which contains a MySQL database DATETIME, the result is always "42 years":

```
// MySQL date is: 2012-01-02 11:22:33
$date1 = mysql_result($result,0,"date");
$date2 = date("Y:m:d H:i", strtotime($date1));
echo humanTiming($date2);
// Result: "42 years"
```

Edit: Here's my second attempt

```
$date1 = mysql_result($result,0,"date");
$date2 = "2012-01-02 11:22:33";
echo "The first date is $date1 which is ";
echo humanTiming( strtotime($date1));
echo ", and the second date is $date2 which is ";
echo humanTiming( strtotime($date2));
// Result: The first date is 2012-01-02 11:22:33 which is , and the second date is 2012-01-02 11:22:33 which is 6 months
```

Comment: Are you sure `$date1` contains what you think it does?

Comment: "echo $date1;" results in "2012-01-02 11:22:33"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `humanTiming()` function expects a UNIX timestamp, not a formatted date, so call it like this:

```
 $date1 = mysql_result($result,0,"date");
 echo humanTiming( strtotime($date1));
```

With your sample date, the [output is](http://viper-7.com/2wzm2N):

```
6 months
```

Comment: That results in nothing at all?

Comment: It shouldnt't, it's the equivalent of writing `echo humanTiming( strtotime( "2012-01-02 11:22:33"));` (**which [works](http://viper-7.com/agfX3b)**), unless that's not the exact date you're getting back from MySQL.

Comment: Your code works, even with a PHP string. Could there be something in the MySQL crossover that I've messed up?

Comment: Possibly - Did you double check your variable names? You are running the exact two lines of code that I have?

Comment: Check out my edit -- it still isn't working with a MySQL string, but works fine with a normal string.

Comment: At the risk of sounding defeatist - should I not use Datetime? Perhaps Timestamp would be smoother?

Comment: Fixed! Looks like it was a MySQL issue. I re-entered the date into the row and it worked fine.